# Inserting text into search bar

Tags: itunes, autoit

I'm trying to insert text into Itunes search bar, but it doesn't do anything. Is ControlSend the best function for doing this?

```
AutoItSetOption("MouseCoordMode", 0)
ControlSend("iTunes","", "Button2", "free apps")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ControlSend should work, but maybe you need to declare the controlID in another way, like this:

```
ControlSend("iTunes","", "[CLASS:Edit; INSTANCE:1]", "free apps")
```

If it doesn't work you could also try the Send() command, but you need the focus on the textbox to use it.